# Deleted partitions still show up under "My Computer" in Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, partitioning

I removed two partitions using Vista diskhandling.

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/khtia3epmxpd2zm/p2.jpg]

The partitions are gone, but the two logical devices still show up under "My Computer" (F and G).

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3fdtz6krf3obofg/p1.jpg]

How can I remove these icons?

Comment: Have you tried rebooting?  Are you suree those are not external drives?  Can you actually navigate to them.

Comment: Reboot will not remove the icons.
They were previously Linux partitions on my single internal disk.
They show up under properties as 0 byte content disks. When navigating to them Vista responds "unavailable location".

Comment: Open a command prompt, run the following command, and then post here the full command output you got: `reg query HKLM /s /f "G:" > "%userprofile%\Desktop\reg1.txt"`